# Using UUID as OWL Jena individuals node ids

Tags: rdf, uuid, jena, owl, ontology

When modeling data in OWL (Ontology Web Language) we can have two types of individuals (elements that belong to a particular class). One of then is unique and the other is a metadata.

For example i can say that: A individual from a class "University" is related by the object property "hasDepartment" with an individual of the class "Department".

"Oxford" hasDepartment "MathDepartment". Now i can talk about the unique Department, the one that belongs to that unique University or i can be referring that Oxford possesses a MathDepartment that other Universities can also possess and it is not the unique Oxford Math Department.

The issue is that in the unique case of the MathDepartment individual we will need a unique NodeID. While Oxford University is unique by default.

My question is:

Is there any bad side effect when using a universally unique identifier (UUID) as individual Node IDs?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here.  Object properties only relate individuals.  You can make the object property assertion "OxfordUniversity hasDepartment MathDepartmentOfOxford" where OxfordUniversity and MathDepartmentOfOxford are both individuals.

Comment: Are you asking how to ensure that a given department can only be a department of a given university?  E.g., to ensure that Oxford's Math Department cannot also be Harvard's Math Department?  You'd usually do that by making the hasDepartment property inverse functional.  That means that if x hasDepartment z and y hasDepartment z, then x = y.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the individual id is the object URI and cannot be repeated. In Jena for example if i add another statement about "MathDepartment" where MathDepartment is the NodeID then it will think it is the same individual even thought i would like it not to be. So i either use a UUID as nodeId and have something like a hasName data property with "MathDepartment" as a string or create a MathDepartment class and associate it with the Univertsity class. Either way i will need to create unique NodeIds. Right?